# ngCordova not recognising Camera, Flashlight, or other parts of Android Phone

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an app using the [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), and [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/)

I have followed the instructions to get the camera working by

- Installing ngCordova with bower
- Including ngCordova.js in a script tag *before* ngCordova.js
- Installing the necessary plugins with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`

I have the example code from the docs included in my main controller:

```
var options = { 
    quality : 75, 
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 100,
    targetHeight: 100,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
  // Success! Image data is here
}, function(err) {
  // An error occured. Show a message to the user
});
```

I then add android as a platform using ionic platform add android, then run the app on my phone using "ionic run" while my LG G2 phone is connected via USB. The problem is, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js:36:45)
at invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11591:17)
at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11602:23)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14906:28
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14295:34
at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7957:20)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14282:11)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13730:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13733:13)
at publicLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13626:30)
```

To figure out whether it was something wrong with ngCordova as a whole, or just specifically the camera function, I also tried to get the flashlight working by the same steps and using the flashlight example code:

var isAvailable = $cordovaFlashlight.available()

$cordovaFlashlight.switchOn()
    .then(
      function (success) { /* success */ },
      function (error) { /* error */ });

When I try to run this, I get a similar error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flashlight' of undefined
at Object.available (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:1243:23)
at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js:36:42)
at invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11591:17)
at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11602:23)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14906:28
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14295:34
at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7957:20)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14282:11)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13730:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13733:13)
```

Does anyone know what could be going on? I feel like I have followed the steps outlined in the documentation correctly.

(As a sanity check, I tried logging the value of window.cordova to check that it is actually there. It is, but interestingly, the cordova.plugins property is an object that only contains the property "Keyboard". I would have expected it to also have some sort of reference to a Camera and Flashlight too. Perhaps this has something to do with the problem?)

Comment: did you pass in the reference to the plugin into your controller? maybe if you post the full code of the controller..

Comment: same problem. Script order: 1. angular, 2. ngcordova, 3. cordova. Added ngCordova as module dependency and Flashlight is listed under `$ cordova plugins` and for sure i use an injection for `cordovaFlashlight`. otherwise you would have another error.

Comment: Do check if oyu have done the same stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a reference to the cordovaFlashlight plugin like the following example

> `module.controller('MyController', function($scope, $cordovaFlashlight) {`